# Drop down menu not dropping down HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

So im having a pretty basic issue, When trying to add a dropdown menu to the navbar to show the options of sorting by price, category, rating etc the dropdown is not working. Ive been trying to read on stack and see if I could find a issue. But no luck yet.

base.html

```
 <div class="col-lg col-sm col-md col-6 flex-grow-0">
    <div class="category-wrap dropdown d-inline-block float-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> All Categories
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}" class="dropdown-item">All Products</a>
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}?category=price" class="dropdown-item">By Price</a>
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}?category=rating" class="dropdown-item">By Rating</a>
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}?category=wheight" class="dropdown-item">By Wheight</a>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- category-wrap.// -->
</div>
```

nav.html

```
 <div class="col-lg col-sm col-md col-6 flex-grow-0">
    <div class="category-wrap dropdown d-inline-block float-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> All Categories
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}" class="dropdown-item">All Products</a>
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}?category=price" class="dropdown-item">By Price</a>
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}?category=rating" class="dropdown-item">By Rating</a>
            <a href="{% url 'products' %}?category=wheight" class="dropdown-item">By Wheight</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Im not a pro coder yet but trying to get there

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [repro] as debugging details. Also tag accordingly. Your code indicates the usage of Bootstrap and a JS Framework. PS: With your edit your code is invalid. Neither `<div \>` nor `</a\>` does exist

Comment: Thank you for the feedeback, trying to improve on the asking questions part. Sorry about that brother

Comment: alright, now it would still be required to mention the JS-Framework you use.

Comment: I am unsure what JS framework I use tbh..

Comment: Where is that coming from? `% url 'products' %`

Comment: its coming form a app called products in modls.py

Comment: Perhaps update your post with the ACTUAL **rendered** HTML and CSS that you have tried so we may best assist you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap 4 I would refer to the bootstrap documentation for the dropdown component:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

You might double-check functionality by taking the exact snippet from the documentation, see if that works in your code base and continue from there. If it does also not work, based on what we know, you have to debug by checking the browser console. In case the bootstrap 4 script is being on an error or not being loaded or the submodule for dropdowns not being in your distributed JS.